# Selecting contained document elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, svg

I have a [page](http://dhappy.org/.../geo/usa/37618/Riddle%20Creek/665/xhtml) where I am attempting to pull the layer names from a svg document and make a sliding menu controlling their visibility.

My page looks like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>665 Riddle Creek</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav/>
    <object id="map" type="image/svg+xml" data="svg"></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to pull the layers from the svg and create a list in `nav`. I am having difficulty selecting the layers from the svg. I have tried the following:

```
$('[inkscape\\:groupmode="layer"]', $('#map').first().contextDocument)
$($('#map').first().contextDocument).find( '[inkscape\\:groupmode="layer"]' )
$('#map').contents().find( '[inkscape\\:groupmode="layer"]' )
```

All methods return 0 elements. What should I do?

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PF8Y8/1/) for the issue and my problem seems to originate from the `contentDocument` being set to an empty html document rather than my svg.

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of your document here, not just a link to it.

Comment: can you post the relevant html?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the svg document isn't necessarily loaded when `jQuery.ready` handlers are called. I was able to access the document with the following code:

```
$( function() {
    var svgElem = document.getElementById("map")
    svgElem.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var svg = this.contentDocument
        $('nav').append( layersList( $(svg.documentElement) ) )
    }, false)
} )
```

The function to build the list them looks like:

```
function layersList( $root ) {
    var $children = $root.children( '[inkscape\\:groupmode="layer"]' )
    var $list = $('<ul/>')
    $children.each( function() {
        ⋮
    } )
    return $list
}
```